# Creating a timetable on the basis of slot given by the user in ios

Tags: ios

I want to store a user slots in a week timetable
For eg. a user has A slot which occurs on 8-8:50Am on monday, 9-9:50 on tuesday and 11:00-11:50 on friday and has more slots like B , C , D , E which occurs on fixed times of fixed times of the week.
Please suggest what concept i should use, like dictionary or What
i am a beginner :P

Comment: How about an enum instance variable on users?

Answer (score 0):

1. If user time table data can be altered

You can define a core data with .xcuserdata and create a required tables and push data into those entities.

2. If its a static time table,

You can add these details into .plist file (because using .plist file, you can store the structured data like array,dictionary,etc....).

For your requirement `NSDictionary` is suggestible key is week name and value is slot timing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this library.
Name : `Elliotable` (ios time table)

URL : https://github.com/della-padula/Elliotable

You can customize time table. You can change the color of border and background colour, WeekdaySymbol, Event Item Attributes and etc.